Sobolev space $H^{1/2}$ and smooth functions on $S^1$
As far as I know some $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ and this also holds for a Lipschitz domain $\Omega$, in that case, $C^{\infty}(\overline{\Omega})$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$.
What about the case of $H^{1/2}(S^1)$? Is $C^{\infty}(S^1)$ dense in $H^{1/2}(S^1)$? Is it even a subspace?
